# Replicating Java password hashing code in Node.js (PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1)

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, hash, pbkdf2

*Edit: my question has been updated, check the bottom of this post for the latest issue. I left the rest up for people who want to read the whole story :)*

I've been working on translating a small Java application into Node.js, which for the most part has been going very well. I've had to look up a lot of Java functions to figure out what they do and how to replicate their behaviour in Node (since I have pretty much no experience whatsoever with Java), but I got most of the functionality working by now.

Unfortunately there is one bit that I just can't seem to get working. It is a method used to generate a password hash, using a set of high level Java-specific functions that don't seem to exist in Node. I've been trying for two days to get this working but I just can't get the results I want.

This is the original Java code:

```
public static String hashPassword(final String password, final String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    final char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
    final byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes();
    final PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, saltBytes, 1000, 192);
    final SecretKeyFactory key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    final byte[] hashedPassword = key.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(hashedPassword));
}
```

Note: the salt is a fixed value, it is not random. I know this is not how it should be, but this is how the application is set up. So, since the Java code always gets the same result, it should be possible to get the same result in Node as well.

I've tried using `crypto.pbkdf2`, using various ciphers that seemed similar, but it all gave me a different outcome than the Java code. So I figured I'd ask here, to see if anyone knows how to do this, or has any suggestions on how to approach this.

Note that (as I said) I don't know a thing about Java, so my difficulties getting this to work probably come from the fact that I have a hard time grasping just what is happening within this method, and googling the various functions used gives conflicting answers and mostly just shows other people having a hard time with them as well.

So there are actually three questions I'm asking:

1. Is this possible to replicate in Node.js or does Java use functionality that just doesn't exist within Node?
2. Could someone who has more Java experience explain the various lines in this code, and what each one does? Preferably in a way that someone with a decent level of Node.js experience (and some PHP) but who never worked with Java would understand :)
3. If anyone knows, which Node functions am I looking at to get this working? Can I do it with the built-in crypto module or will I need additional modules?

Lastly, before you say "just implement a Node-specific hashing algorithm" (which would be the easier option), I can't do that since this is to be used on existing databases that already contain these hashed passwords and that are used by other existing Java applications as well. Changing the other applications or the database is currently not an option.

**UPDATE**: I've gotten an answer that was very helpful, and now I got this in my Node.js code:

```
hashPassword = function(password, salt){
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, new Buffer(salt), 1000, 24, 'sha1', function(err, key){

    }
}
```

That's where I'm stuck again. I can't get the string value I need from the key. I googled a bit and found out that the `String.format` line in the Java code turns the BigInteger into a hexadecimal integer, but I can't seem to get the correct value.

- I tried simply `key.toString('hex')` but that didn't work.
- I found this [node-biginteger](https://github.com/node-modules/node-biginteger) module, and tried `BigInteger.fromBuffer(1, key).toString(24)` and some variations thereupon, but it still gives me a very different outcome than the Java application.

Any help on how to get the correct string value from the buffer would be very much appreciated.

**Update2**: I finally got my application working, as it turns out it was an external module that outputted bad hashes. Implementing the crypto module properly fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parameters generate the same buffer:

`crypto.pbkdf2('test', 'salt', 1000, 24, 'sha1', function(err, key) {});`

What is left is to format a string the same way. It can be a bit problematic, since `BigInteger` is signed, so you should take sign into account as well.

You can do this as following using [bn.js](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/blob/master/lib/bn.js):

```
function format(key) {
  if (key[0] >>> 7 === 0) {
    return key.toString('hex');
  }

  return '-' + new BN(key.toString('hex'), 16).notn(192).add(new BN(1)).toString(16);
}
```

bn.js doesn't interpret leading bit as a sign, so you have to check it first, and then convert to string according to [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

Comment: The Java code uses a length of 192, but in your code you've set a lenght of 24, any specific reason for this?

Comment: In java it's specified in bits, in node.js - in bytes

Comment: Ah. That clears up so much :) I tried `crypto.pbkdf2` but I set it to 192 since that's what I saw in the Java code, obviously that gave me very different results.

Comment: I'm stuck on the BigInteger thing now, I googled some and found that the last line in the Java method turns the buffer into a hexadecimal integer. Simply calling `.toString('hex')` doesn't work, then I found [this node-biginteger module](https://github.com/node-modules/node-biginteger) and I tried `BigInteger.fromBuffer(1, key).toString(24)` with the key from the crypto function, but it doesn't give me the result I need either. Any tips on how to get the string value?

Comment: Still nothing :( Your `format` function just gives me the result of `key.toString('hex')` which isn't the value I need. I accept that I will need that function to handle a signed value, but the Java code must be doing something else to the data still, and I just have no idea what. And I checked, nothing else happens to the return value of `hashPassword`, it just ends up in `System.out.println(password);`.

Comment: I slept on it and tried again this morning, after some small adjustments I now get the correct value from this function! I still don't get the correct value through the whole process though, but I tracked down the issue and it's actually the previous step in the Java code, where the salt is generated, that outputs something different from my Node code. I updated my original post (see update 2 below the original text). Do you happen to know the answer to that as well? :)

Comment: Aand never mind that, I'm sorry, it turns out the sha1 module I was using just had an error in it causing it to output wrong hashes. I implemented the default crypto module and all is well now. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get this to work with node 6, and it turns out, things have gotten simpler (not needing bigints).  I never would have figured this out without [vkurchatkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391953/vkurchatkin)'s original answer, though:

```
console.log(hashPassword('password', 'salt').toString('hex'));

function hashPassword(password, salt) {
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, Buffer.from(salt, 'hex'), 1000, 24, 'sha1');
}
```